# Search bar is cutting out parts of the characters

Tags: bug, design, search

The search bars are cutting out the bottom parts of some characters with descenders (like g). This is annoying since some of the letters look pretty similar with this (like g and q)
[image: example]

The text above actually is `q g p j`

Can this be changed so the whole letter is shown?

Comment: Are you using an unsupported browser? Looks fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge (current versions).

Comment: @patricksweeney I am using Chrome, do you know how I can check my version?

Comment: Hamburger Menu > Help > About Google Chrome. Current version is 100.

Comment: @patricksweeney Chrome is up to date - Version 100.0.4896.60 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Able to reproduce in the latest Edge.

Comment: Unable to reproduce in Firefox (mobile).

Comment: No repro in chrome 99 on android.

Comment: Already reported, exactly same cause: [Answer sorting menu is cutting off the bottom part of letters](/q/377327/289905).

Comment: It appears and disappears according to the zoom level of the browser, can this be fixed for all settings?

Comment: @SebastianSimon indeed, same root cause which is the font used by SE. It will be cut in any single line textbox in devices supporting this font. Fix would be, well, using other font, that's not being cut.